# Privoxy-like proxy that handles multiple parallel connections?

Tags: windows, proxy-server

I use [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) on my XP host to filter/rewrite web pages, but it's slower because all connections go through Privoxy's single port.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser) on StackOverflow, by default, browsers support more than one simultaneous connection, which would explain why going through Privoxy is slower.

Does someone know of a similar application that could handle more than one connection?

Thank you.